# How to make the top level endpoint public when authorization is used in eve?

Tags: eve

I am working on a REST API with python-eve. I use authorization with a subclass of the default TokenAuth class as described in the documentation. However now a GET Request to / replies with error code 401 and the message "Please provide proper credentials".

I want a GET request to / to just return the default list of available resources without authorization.

For a regular endpoint I would just add GET to the public_methods property in the schema, but / does not have a schema, how can I make it a public endpoint again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the other way around. Set `PUBLIC_METHODS` to `['GET']` so home endpoint is accessible. Then you set `public_methods` to `[]` for every protected resource.